# Cannot convert from HttpContextBase to HttpContextBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq

With the following code (using Moq 4.0.10501.6):

```
HomeController controller = new HomeController();
ActionResult result = _controller.Index();

Mock<HttpResponseBase> response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

Mock<HttpContextBase> httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
httpContext.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);

Mock<ControllerContext> controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext.Setup(c => c.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext.Object);
result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext.Object);
```

...I get the following compiler errors:

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
'Moq.Language.IReturns<System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext,
 System.Web.HttpContextBase>.Returns(System.Web.HttpContextBase)'
has some invalid arguments

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpContextBase
[c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\
v4.0\System.Web.dll]' to 'System.Web.HttpContextBase'
```

What have I done wrong? Why can't I convert from `HttpContextBase` to `HttpContextBase`?

I started with an ASP.NET MVC project, added an NUnit test project and ReSharper sorted out the missing System.Web reference. According to the properties window in VS, the System.Web.dll that I'm referencing is the one in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discovered (thanks Reflector) that `HttpContextBase` is actually in `System.Web.dll, Version 4.0.0.0` *and* in `System.Web.Abstractions, Version 3.5.0.0`.

So, I fixed it by adding a reference to `System.Web.Abstractions, Version 4.0.0.0` to the project.

Oddly, however, `System.Web.Abstractions, Version 4.0.0.0` *doesn't* contain `HttpContextBase`.

So, I'm still not sure what's going on, but at least it's compiling now.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS! I still don't understand how in the world could adding this reference resolve the problem, but at least I can move on writing my tests.... Ta

Answer (score 1):

May be `System.Web` uses something in `System.Web.Abstractions` within `HttpContextBase`.

So, probably `HttpContextBase` Class has something tied to `System.Web.Abstractions`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have referenced different versions of the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly. Try removing all references to this assembly in your projects and adding it from the GAC.

Comment: HttpContextBase is in System.Web.dll, not System.Web.Mvc.dll, so why should that matter? Also, the versions of both System.Web.dll and System.Web.Mvc.dll are the same in both projects.

Comment: Ah. I see where you're going with this: HttpContextBase is in `System.Web 4.0.0.0`, *and* in `System.Web.Abstractions 3.5.0.0`. ControllerContext is in `System.Web.Mvc 2.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this could be fixed with an assembly redirect instead of referencing a .NET 3.5 assembly in a .NET 4.0 project?